# How to select odd "option" using nth-child() in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to sharpen my jQuery skills by learning to use `nth-child` selector but with little luck.  I'm sure I'm just doing something slightly wrong, and I will have a follow up question to this again regarding nth-child, so any help is appreciated.

I would have thought my code below would have select "Saab" and "Audi" in the pulldown menu, but what it does is return the "source" `select` element, `select#carsmenu`.  What am I doing wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      console.log($('#carsmenu:nth-child(odd)').prop('selected', true));
});
```

```html
<select multiple id="carsmenu">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You may want to look into using `find()` instead to lessen the confusion. E.g., `$('#carsmenu').find(':ng-child(odd)').prop('selected', true)`.

Comment: Of course, then need to change to `even` instead

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan is :ng-child is something angular specific?

Comment: What if I already have selected `$("#carsmenu")`?  Is there any way to then use an nth-child selector against the returned value(s)?

Comment: @GeorgeJempty No, just a typo from too much Angular work :). Should be the same as your selector `nth-child`.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan so that might answer my subsequent question/comment: use `nth-child()` inside find when I already have made a DOM selection I want to use as the source

Answer (score 2):

The [`:nth-child()`](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) selector should written after target element that you want to select it.

```
$('#carsmenu > :nth-child(odd)').prop('selected', true);
```

```js
$('#carsmenu > :nth-child(odd)').prop('selected', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple id="carsmenu">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Also you can use [`:odd`](https://api.jquery.com/odd-selector/) selector

```
$('#carsmenu > :odd').prop('selected', true);
```

```js
$('#carsmenu > :odd').prop('selected', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple id="carsmenu">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

With `#carsmenu:nth-child(odd)` this code, you'are selecting select element that odd, what you really want it select child element of select, in your case is `<option>` tag, you might use below code for selecting child elements :

```
// This will select volvo and mercedes because of 0-based of nth-child
// another option is `even` which select saab and audi 
$('#carsmenu option:nth-child(odd)')
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log($('#carsmenu option:nth-child(even)').prop('selected', true));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple id="carsmenu">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Yes and it selects Volvo and Mercedes instead because it is 1-based not 0-based

Comment: you might need used even instead

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //It is possible as this,
  console.log($('#carsmenu :nth-child(odd)')); //Volov & Mercedes, it starts counting from the first child "Volvo" and takes every second "Mercedes"--> ...
  console.log($('#carsmenu :odd')); //Saab & Audi, it starts counting from element 0, which does not exist, and takes every second --> "Saab" --> "Audi" --> ...

  //but for a better readability:
  console.log($('#carsmenu option:nth-child(odd)')); //Volov & Mercedes
  console.log($('#carsmenu option:odd')); //Saab & Audi

  //add the ".prop('selected', true);" to which you want to have selected.
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple id="carsmenu">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```